# Opencv Android color detection

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk

I'm a beginner in openCV4android and I try to make a red color detection with front camera, can you give me the way/step to make it. because this is important for my final project on my campuss..

Comment: Please share the code that you tried with.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the step you need to do in short.

1. Convert BGR image to HSV, as HSV is proffered colour space in color based segmentation.
2. Use [inrange()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#inrange) to segment color.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22299624/human-skin-detecting-with-opencv/22300024#22300024) you can find HSV-Color wheel which will help you to select correct HSV range for your color.

Comment: how to determine the color red, I do not understand what you describe, I tried to make a laser detection ponter in the cave with front camera android OpenCV, and I know Keith to start, can you explain how? 
I am just a beginner

Comment: First you have to find the HSV Colour range for red, then convert each frame from to HSV, then do inRange() using above threshold, here you will get binary image representing  red.